# Python: add new row values to a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to form a new matrix called new_matrix with values from a list of lists

```
similair = [1,2,3]
indices=[[0 2]
         [1 2]
         [2 1]]


new_matrix = np.array([])
for list in indices:
    newrow=[]
    for number in list:
        newrow.append(similair[number])
    new_matrix.vstack((new_matrix, np.array(newrow)) )

print new_matrix
```

Desired out put

```
   values
    [1,3]
    [2,3]
    [3,2]
```

however I get the following error

> new_matrix.vstack((new_matrix, np.array(newrow)) )
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'vstack'

Comment: The error is telling you that the object `new_matrix` (which is a numpy array) doesn't have a method called `vstack`.  That's because `vstack` is a numpy function that you access like `np.vstack`.

Answer (score 4):

Use advanced integer indexing ([intro](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays), [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)):

```
import numpy as np
similair = np.array([1,2,3])
indices=np.array([[0, 2],
                  [1, 2],
                  [2, 1]])
new_matrix = similair[indices]
print(new_matrix)
```

yields

```
[[1 3]
 [2 3]
 [3 2]]
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I want each value of the list of lists to be on a new row

Comment: You can just do the following: for item in result: print(item)

Comment: @Mark Hannel indeed I can do that but I want to further use the matrix I build

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the matrix as follows

```
similair = [1,2,3]
indices=[[0 2]
         [1 2]
         [2 1]]
new_matrix = [[similar[i] for i in index] for index in indices]
```

If you want new_matrix to be a numpy array you can just use the `array` command

```
import numpy as np
new_matrix = np.array(new_matrix)
```